# Composite types in Julia: Dictionaries as a named field?

Tags: dictionary, julia, composite-types

I'd like to make a composite type that includes a dictionary as one of its named fields. But the obvious syntax doesn't work. I'm sure there's something fundamental that I don't understand. Here's an example:

```
type myType
    x::Dict()
end
```

Julia says: `type: myType: in type definition, expected Type{T<:Top}, got Dict{Any,Any}` which means, I'm guessing, that a dictionary is not a of `Any` as any named field must be. But I'm not sure how to tell it what I mean.

I need an named field that is a dictionary. An inner constructor will initialize the dictionary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a subtle difference in the syntax between *types* and *instances*.  `Dict()` instantiates a dictionary, whereas `Dict` by itself is the type.  When defining a composite type, the field definitions need to be of the form `symbol::Type`.

That error message is a little confusing.  What it's effectively saying is this:

> in type definition, expected *something with the type* `Type{T<:Top}`, got *an instance of type* `Dict{Any,Any}`.
>
> In other words, it expected something like `Dict`, which is a `Type{Dict}`, but instead got `Dict()`, which is a `Dict{Any,Any}`.

The syntax you want is `x::Dict`.

Answer (score 5):

`Dict()` creates a dictionary, in particular a `Dict{Any,Any}` (i.e. keys and values can have any type, `<:Any`). You want the field to be of **type** `Dict`, i.e.

```
type myType
    x::Dict
end
```

If you know the key and value types, you could even write, e.g.

```
type myType
    x::Dict{Int,Float64}
end
```